# Sails multiple models associate

Tags: javascript, model, associations, sails.js, populate

I have following models:

Comment.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id : {
            type : 'integer',
            primaryKey : true
        },
        objectId : {
            type : 'string',
            required : true
        },
        comment : {
            type : 'string',
            required : true
        }
    }

};
```

Image.js and Video.js are the same:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id : {
            type : 'integer',
            primaryKey : true
        },
        name : {
           type: 'string'
        },
        comments : {
            collection : 'comment',
            via : 'objectId'
        }

     }

 };
```

When i try populate comments with Video or Image model array is always empty (some comments are inserted for both)..

```
Image.find({id: 1}).populate('comments').exec(function(err, image) {
   console.log(image);
});
```

Or this...

```
Video.find({id: 1}).populate('comments').exec(function(err, video) {
   console.log(video);
});
```

I want to separate video and image models, and for comments i want use combined table.

Tnx

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Image.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id : {
            type : 'integer',
            primaryKey : true
        },
        name : {
           type: 'string'
        },
        comments : {
            collection : 'comment',
            via : 'image'
        }

     }

 };
```

Comment.js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        id : {
            type : 'integer',
            primaryKey : true
        },
        image : {
           model: 'image'
        },
        comment : {
            type : 'string',
            required : true
        }
    }

};
```

Quering

```
sails> Image.create({id:1, name: 'Image'}).then(console.log)

sails> Comment.create({id:1, comment: 'Comment', image: 1}).then(console.log)

sails>Image.find().populate('comments').then(console.log)

sails> [ { comments: 
     [ { id: 1,
         comment: 'Comment',
         image: 1,
         createdAt: Wed Feb 11 2015 15:13:50 GMT-0430 (VET),
         updatedAt: Wed Feb 11 2015 15:13:50 GMT-0430 (VET) } ],
    id: 1,
    name: 'Image',
    createdAt: Wed Feb 11 2015 15:13:01 GMT-0430 (VET),
    updatedAt: Wed Feb 11 2015 15:13:01 GMT-0430 (VET) } ]
```

Comment: Do you have some join table? How do you insert comment data ?

Comment: Which sails.js and waterline version you use?

Comment: I know this works, but what if i want store in comment table comments from separate image and video models?